# Stub current_user when testing devise views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I am testesting my custom devise views with capybara and i need a logged in user in order to tests some views, for example:

```
feature 'user/edit' do
  describe "the edit profile process", :type => :feature do
    include Devise::TestHelpers

    let!(:user){ FactoryGirl.build(:user)

    def sign_in(user)
      if user.nil?
        request.env['warden'].stub(:authenticate!).
          and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})
          controller.stub :current_user => nil
      else
        request.env['warden'].stub :authenticate! => user
         controller.stub :current_user => user
      end
    end

    it "update " do
      sign_in(user)
      visit '/users/edit'
      within("#edit_user") do  
         #=> something
      end
      click_on 'Update'
      page.should have_content("something")
    end
  end
end
```

But i got this error

```
Failure/Error: request.env['warden'].stub :authenticate! => user

NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Where do you expect `request` to be defined?

Comment: i expect it is defined in Devise::TestHelpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `Devise::TestHelpers` establishes the `@request` instance variable. You are referencing `request`, which is apparently set to `nil` in some other accessible scope, resulting in the error you're getting.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/b8ed2f31608eccb6df6d5bb2e66238d6dfc4bcfc/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb for the source of `TestHelpers`.

Comment: Thank you, i had to expect that!

Comment: That's weird because both `@request` and `request` works for me. `request` is accessible as well as `warden`, `controller` and `response`.

Comment: None of the standard docs https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs mention using the @request ivar.  Wonder why if it's a valid option.